# Call to undefined function in Laravel 4

Tags: function, laravel, laravel-4

I have set up a resource in Laravel 4 for an entity "Artists";  Within the ArtistController, I have added a function of my own, youtube_embed.  When I call this function in my view (the show view), it is saying that it is undeclared.  Do you have any idea why I am receiving this error?  Thank you.

Here is the code:

in ArtistController:

```
 public function youtube_embed($vari) {

        $step1=explode('v=', $vari);
        $step2 =explode('&amp;',$step1[1]);
        $iframe ='<iframe style="border:4px solid #41759d" width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step1[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

        return $iframe;

    }
```

in the show.blade.php:

```
{{youtube_embed($artist->video_path);}}
```

Thank you again for your help.

Comment: Your youtube_embed function is a method of the Controller class. right?
How can you access is without an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's lot of way to achieve this.

- You could include the file at the bottom of app/start/global.php
- You could make a helpers class

  1. Create a folder in app called "helpers" along with a file called Embed.php
  2. add "app/helpers" to composer.json in the "autoload.classmap" section. Watch out for commas.
  3. In app/start/global.php, add app_path().'/helpers' in the ClassLoader::addDirectories array. This step is not necessary but it prevents you from doing composer dump-autoload everytime you add a new helper.
  4. in app/helpers/Embed.php, you could do something like this

     ```
     class Embed {
       public static function youtube($vari) {

         $step1 = explode('v=', $vari);
         $step2 = explode('&amp;', $step1[1]);
         $iframe = '<iframe style="border:4px solid #41759d" width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step1[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

         return $iframe;
       }
     }
     ```

  And use it in blade like this

  ```
  {{Embed::youtube($artist->video_path)}}
  ```

  That way, if you want to add embed vimeo, you could also add it and call it like

  ```
  {{Embed::vimeo($artist->video_path)}}
  ```
- You could make a custom form macro

  ```
  Form::macro('youtube', function($vari) {
     $step1 = explode('v=', $vari);
     $step2 = explode('&amp;', $step1[1]);
     $iframe = '<iframe style="border:4px solid #41759d" width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step1[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

      return $iframe;
  });
  ```

  and call it like this

  ```
  {{ Form::youtube($artist->video_path) }}
  ```

So many possibilities! :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is just a helper. I would do this in my app.

Firstly, create a folder "helpers" in your "app" folder.

Then create a file named "common.php" inside the "helpers" folder. Put your function in this file:

```
    <?php

        if ( ! function_exists('image'))
        {
            function youtube_embed($vari)
            {
                 $step1=explode('v=', $vari);
                         $step2 =explode('&amp;',$step1[1]);
                         $iframe ='<iframe style="border:4px solid #41759d" width="460" height="259" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$step1[1].'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';

                         return $iframe;
            }
         }
```

Next, include this file in your route.php.

```
  <?php

      include('libraries/common.php');
```

And you can use your function inside your application.